# Multiple conditional value replacement for the purpose of tidying data

Tags: r

```html
Code        Type
123456      1
1234567     1
12345678    1
A123456     1
12345678    1
            1
2345678     2
```

I am trying to prepend 0 to values in the Code column if two criteria are met:
i) the Code value is a number (does not include letters or NA).
ii) the type column is equal to 1
This is so that certain values are a uniform 8 characters for an API request I am building.

I have tried using the following:

```
  if(Type = 1 & !is.na(Code)) { 
        with_options(
        c(scipen = 999), 
        str_pad(Code, 8, pad = "0")
        )
    }
```

for the above example I'd expect row one to update to 00123456, row two to 01234567. All the other examples should stay the same.

I get the following error

```
Warning message:
In if (Type = 1 & !is.na(Code)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I have tried doing this in multiple ways and still get an error.

Comment: You have to use `Type == 1` to compare values, not `Type = 1`. 
Then instead of `if`  use `ifelse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem. I'm using `dplyr` for better readability, but it could also be implemented without it (using base `ifelse`)

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

data <- 
  structure(list(Code = c("123456", "1234567", "12345678", "A123456", "12345678", "", "2345678"),
                 Type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("Code", "Type"), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

data %>% 
  mutate(Code_new = if_else(!str_detect(Code, "[^\\d]") & Type == 1, 
                            str_pad(data$Code, width = 8, side = "left", pad = "0"), 
                            Code)) 
#       Code Type Code_new
# 1   123456    1 00123456
# 2  1234567    1 01234567
# 3 12345678    1 12345678
# 4  A123456    1  A123456
# 5 12345678    1 12345678
# 6             1 00000000
# 7  2345678    2  2345678
```

Explanation: 
First I check the conditions for modifying the Code column with  
 `!str_detect(Code, "[^\\d]") & Type == 1`. 
If you want to ensure, that there's at least one digit in your Code variable, add 
 
`& str_detect(Code, "\\d")` to the conditions.

If the conditions are met, then the Code is padded with 0s, otherwise the original Code entry is returned. 
Using `if_else` instead of `ifelse` ensures, that the `TRUE` and `FALSE` statements return the same vector type.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your solution is nearly there. When I use if_else with my data I get the following error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `false` must be type character, not integer. Meanwhile, if I just use ifelse I return 1 in Code_new for values where there is no code value, but otherwise works ok. Any idea how to prevent the 1?

Comment: As the error says, your Code variable is stored as integer, but in this case it is probably a factor. If you replace `Code` with `as.character(Code)` it should work fine.